# Dynamically created Radio button Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to dynamically create 2 radio buttons on selecting an already existing radio button.

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="select" value="m" id="op1" />1
    <br>
    <div id="radioDiv1"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv2"></div>

    <input type="radio" name="select" value="f" id="op2" />2
    <br>
    <div id="radioDiv3"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv4"></div>
</form>
```

This is my Jquery:

```
$('#op1').click(function() {
    $('#radioDiv1').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv1').append('A');
    $('#radioDiv2').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv2').append('B');
});
$('#op2').click(function() {
    $('#radioDiv3').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv3').append('C');
    $('#radioDiv4').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv4').append('D');
});
```

Suppose I click on 1, i need radio buttons A and B to appear. Suppose I want to change my selection from 1 to 2, I need A and B to disappear and C and D to appear. However, the radio buttons do not disappear. Also, on going back from option 2 to 1, another set of A and B are created.
Is there any way to make the radio buttons appear and disappear on particular selection? Thanks.

Comment: Because when you click radio button it appends new radio buttons every time, i suggest you to add radio buttons only once and then toggle it according to need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear before doing it:

```js
$('#op1').click(function() {
    $('#radioDiv1, #radioDiv2, #radioDiv3, #radioDiv4').html('');
    $('#radioDiv1').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv1').append('A');
    $('#radioDiv2').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv2').append('B');
});
$('#op2').click(function() {
    $('#radioDiv1, #radioDiv2, #radioDiv3, #radioDiv4').html('');
    $('#radioDiv3').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv3').append('C');
    $('#radioDiv4').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv4').append('D');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="select" value="m" id="op1" />1
    <br>
    <div id="radioDiv1"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv2"></div>

    <input type="radio" name="select" value="f" id="op2" />2
    <br>
    <div id="radioDiv3"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv4"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="select" value="m" id="op1" />1
    <br>
    <div id="radioDiv1"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv2"></div>

    <input type="radio" name="select" value="f" id="op2" />2
    <br>
    <div id="radioDiv3"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv4"></div>
</form>
$('#op1').click(function() {
    $('#radioDiv1').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv1').append('A');
    $('#radioDiv2').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv2').append('B');
    $('#radioDiv3').hide();
    $('#radioDiv4').hide();
        $('#radioDiv1').show();
    $('#radioDiv2').show();
});
$('#op2').click(function() {
    $('#radioDiv3').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv3').append('C');
    $('#radioDiv4').append('<input type="radio" />');
    $('#radioDiv4').append('D');
     $('#radioDiv1').hide();
    $('#radioDiv2').hide();
        $('#radioDiv3').show();
    $('#radioDiv4').show();
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/hhjoo40b/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
$('#op1').click(function() {
        $('#radioDiv1').append('<input type="radio" />');
        $('#radioDiv1').append('A');
        $('#radioDiv2').append('<input type="radio" />');
        $('#radioDiv2').append('B');
        $('#radioDiv3').html('');
        $('#radioDiv4').html('');
    });
    $('#op2').click(function() {
        $('#radioDiv3').append('<input type="radio" />');
        $('#radioDiv3').append('C');
        $('#radioDiv4').append('<input type="radio" />');
        $('#radioDiv4').append('D');
        $('#radioDiv1').html('');
        $('#radioDiv2').html('');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="select" value="m" id="op1" />1
    <br>
    <div id="radioDiv1"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv2"></div>

    <input type="radio" name="select" value="f" id="op2" />2
    <br>
    <div id="radioDiv3"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv4"></div>
</form>
```